# Guess the touched UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiimageview

I have multiple UIImageViews with userinteraction enabled. I am implementing touchesBegan, is there a way to guess which imageview was touched rather than making a rect based on all imageviews and check for the touch point existence in them?

I also have assigned different tags to each imageview.

Answer (score 1):

In your touchesBegan:withEvent: method you can check the UITouch object for its 'view' property. From the docs: "The value of the property is the view object in which the touch originally occurred".

Comment: Use -Wformat to avoid this error. There's also an Xcode setting for this.